# Phaser won't render assets in React app but no problem outside of React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, phaser-framework

I've integrated Phaser into React app. I'm facing difficulty rendering
assets though. Assets render just fine outside of React application with server and template rendered but getting error when I use it with React.

Home.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import Phaser from 'phaser';
import GameComponent from './GameComponent';


class MyGame extends Phaser.Scene {
    
    preload() {
        this.load.image('bg1', './assets/bgs/bg1.png');
        this.load.image('field', './assets/field.png');
        this.load.image('char', './assets/characters/woman.png');
        
    }

    create() {
        this.add.image(0, 0, 'bg1').setOrigin(0, 0);
        
    }
}
    
const Home = () => {
    const config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        scene: [MyGame],
        parent: 'phaser-container',
        scale: {
            mode: Phaser.Scale.ScaleModes.RESIZE,
            width: window.innerWidth,
            height: window.innerHeight
        },
        physics: {
            default: 'arcade',
            arcade: {
                gravity: {y: 200},
            },
        },
    };
    return <div><GameComponent config={config} /></div>
}

export default Home;
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.60.0/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.min.js"></script>
    <title>Family Trip</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Directory structure:

[image]

Console output:

[image]

Any suggestion as to why React has trouble loading the assets ?

Answer (score 0):

Phaser integrated into React looks for assets in the `/public/assets` directory by default. Moving the assets directory into `/public` fixed the issue.

Found solution here: https://github.com/phaserjs/template-react